# How to resolve detached HEAD after git merge main

Tags: git, github

I've a pull request in a remote repository. Assume that the branch name is `feature/create-new-button`. After some changes on folder structure have been made in the `main` branch, `feature/create-new-button` still keeps the previous folder structure (which is expected). To resolve this conflict, I followed the steps stated on GitHub.

1. Switch to the branch

```
$ git branch -a
* main
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remote/origin/feature/create-new-button

$ git checkout remote/origin/feature/create-new-button
```

2. After I merge main into `feature/create-new-button`, the new folder structure was reflected. However, I observed that HEAD has detached from this point onwards

```
$ git merge main
$ git status
HEAD detached from origin/feature/create-new-button
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

3. I committed some changes and decided to push it. Then this error message was returned

```
$ git push -u origin feature/create-new-button
error: src refspec feature/create-new-button does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to "github.com:<repo-name>.git"
```

In this situation, how can I resolve it without creating a new pull request?

Comment: Note: in your step 1 you should have checked out a local instance for the branch, i.e. `git checkout feature/create-new-button` then you would not have had a detached HEAD, it would have created it and linked it in config to the remote counterpart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to push specifying `@` (a.k.a. `HEAD`) as the source, because you do not have a *local* branch called `feature/create-new-button`. Also, because you are not working on a local branch, `-u` has no effect. So, this should work:

```
git push origin @:feature/create-new-button
```

And to get out of `detached HEAD`, just checkout a local branch.

As a side note, did this really work? `git checkout remote/origin/feature/create-new-button`. It looks wrong to be. It should have been `git checkout origin/feature/create-new-button`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works :) As a side note, `git checkout remote/origin/feature/create-new-button` works too but will stick with `git checkout origin/feature/create-new-button` moving forward

Comment: @zZzZ ...if you do so you'll detach HEAD each time. If you don't have a local version of the branch yet, just check it out with `git checkout feature/create-new-button`

Answer (score -1):

If the remote branch already exists and you are trying to push changes to it, you might need to force push if the commit history was changed due to the merge:

```
git push -f origin branch_name
```

Comment: But it's not the case since OP got `error: src refspec feature/create-new-button does not match any` . Adding force to failed push commands without reading error messages is not a good idea.